# How to prevent SQL injections in manually created queries?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am using cakephp and below query has sql injection that i know. But the question is how to fix this in same query . I dont want to use other method. Please dont unvoted it

```
Search->query("select * from subcategories where subcat_name like '%".$_GET['searchkey']."%' and subcat_status='active' ");
```

Comment: You should never add untrusted data directly to the query string. Use prepared/parameterized queries.

Comment: @JimL hi I need example ,so please avoid suggestions

Comment: You can find an example in the cake docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want to use other method

You should use whatever provides the required functionality, not the method that you like more over others!

Also you should never access superglobals directly in CakePHP, this will only bring you in trouble, especially in unit tests. User the proper abstracted methodes provided by the request object, that is `CakeRequest::query()`.

**[Cookbook > Controllers > Request and Response objects > Accessing Querystring parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters)**

---

### Use prepared statements

That being said, use prepared statements, either by passing the values to bind to the second argument of `Model::query()`:

```
$result = $this->Search->query(
    "select * from subcategories where subcat_name like ? and subcat_status='active'",
    array('%' . $this->request->query('searchkey') . '%')
);
```

**[API > Model::query()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-Model.html#_query)**

or by using `DboSource::fetchAll()`, which accepts parameters as the second argument too:

```
$db = $this->Search->getDataSource();
$result = $db->fetchAll(
    "select * from subcategories where subcat_name like ? and subcat_status='active'",
    array('%' . $this->request->query('searchkey') . '%')
);
```

- **[Cookbook > Models > Retrieving Your Data > Prepared Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements)**
- **[API > DboSource::fetchAll()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-DboSource.html#_fetchAll)**

### Escape manually

For the sake of completeness, it's also possible to manually escape the value via `DboSource::value()`, **however you should avoid constructing query strings that way at all costs**, as a small mistake can end up causing an unescaped value to be inserted, thus creating a possible SQL injection vulnerability:

```
$searchkey = $this->request->query('searchkey');

$db = $this->Search->getDataSource();
$value = $db->value('%' . $searchkey . '%', 'string');

$result = $this->Search->query(
    "select * from subcategories where subcat_name like $value and subcat_status='active'"
);
```

**[API > DboSource::value()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-DboSource.html#_value)**

Comment: sir can you solve this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657877/how-to-pass-parameter-to-stop-sqlinjection-in-cakephp

Comment: hi sir but ids=41,589,572 in this case its converting into string

Answer (score -2):

You should totally avoid this way of constructing queries. 
Since You have tagged cakephp 2.0,2.3 Sanitize::escape(string,conn) may fit to Your needs.

```
Search->query(Sanitize::escape("select * from subcategories where subcat_name like '%".$_GET['searchkey']."%' and subcat_status='active'"));
```

Comment: Cake 2.x seem to support prepared/parameterized queries which is a much better solution than trying to escape the query.