# How to prevent SQL Injection in parameters with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

How to prevent SQL Injection while fetching data from the database when using parameters received from the user input:

```
if(isset($_GET['cityval']) && $_GET['cityval'] !=''){

    $city = $this->request->query('cityval'); 

      $searching .= " and college_city in ($city) ";
    } else {
        $searching .= "";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['scholarship']) && $_GET['scholarship'] !=''){
        $searching .= " and college_scholarship = '".$_GET['scholarship']."' ";
    } else {
        $searching .= "";
    }
```

And my main query is below

```
$search = $this->Search->query("select * from  colleges where college_id!='' and status='active' $searching order by $order desc limit $start, 10 ");
```

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use raw queries.**  Simply use the query builder CakePHP provides, and it will prevent injection for you. See the online CakePHP book for more information.

It is SUPER rare to need to use raw queries in CakePHP.

Answer (score 3):

What you try to do is obviously to search by get parameters. There is a wonderful plugin that makes it pretty easy https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search

It could be actually that easy with the plugin:

```
$query = $this->Colleges->find('search', [
    'search' => $this->request->query
]);
$this->set('results', $this->Paginator->paginate($query));
```

The search params itself will be handled in the model layer, check the plugins documentation on that. And the framework will take care of sanitizing the input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Cake ORM uses PDO:

> Underneath the covers, the query builder uses PDO prepared statements
>   which protect against SQL injection attacks.

Reference: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Unfortunately the way you're creating the query is vulnerable as you're not using Cake ORM neither PDO prepared statements.

If you want to use raw queries you could do something like this to protect your code:

```
// Add this in the beginning of the file/code:
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

// Replace connection_name with the name of your connection (maybe it's "default")
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('connection_name');

$bindList = [];

$city = $this->request->query('cityval');

// PDO as a limitation for the parameter markers. See in the comments below
$cityList = array_filter(explode(',', $city), function($item) {
     return preg_match('/^\d+$/', $item);
});

$csvCity = implode(',', $cityList);


$scholarship = $this->request->query('scholarship');

if (!empty($csvCity)) {
    $searching .= " and college_city in ($csvCity)";
}

if (!empty($scholarship)) {
    $searching .= " and college_scholarship = :scholarship";
    $bindList['scholarship'] = $scholarship;
}

$stmt = $connection->prepare($searching);
$stmt->bind($bindList);
$stmt->execute();

// Read all rows.
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');

// Read rows through iteration.
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Do work
}
```

PDO has a limitation and because of that there's no proper way to use the SQL `IN()` clause in a prepared statement (to bind the values to it), so we need to parse manually the values to be inside that clause as I did in the code.

From the [PDO Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) manual page:

> Note: Parameter markers can represent a complete data literal only.
>   Neither part of literal, nor keyword, nor identifier, nor whatever
>   arbitrary query part can be bound using parameters. For example, you
>   cannot bind multiple values to a single parameter in the IN() clause
>   of an SQL statement.

**References**

- [CakePHP 3.3 Cookbook - Database basics](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html)
- [PHP Manual - PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: hi this will return an array and how can you put an array into query

Comment: if (!empty($city)) {
    // PDO as a limitation for the parameter markers. See in the comments below
    $cityList = array_filter(explode(',', $city), function($item) {
        return preg_match('/^\d+$/', $item);
    });
    $searching .= " and college_city in ($cityList)";
}

Comment: I just updated the code. Sorry for that. I forgot to add the implode() as I'm not running/testing the code

Comment: IF SOMEBODY PASS 1' AGAIN IT THROWING ERROR

Comment: Moved the validation for the city array. Test please.

Comment: i have moved this is due to your condition if we user passed 1 thats ok but if user passed 1' then condition failed

Comment: This is expected because the code is accepting only integers for the `$city`. As you didn't mention what was in that variable I presumed it was a string with city IDs separated by comma: `$city = "1,2,3,4,5"`.

What do you have in your `cityval` variable originally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133187/discussion-between-wcomnisky-and-user3198563).

Comment: This is the totally wrong way to use the frameworks datasource and ORM.

Comment: If you read properly I didn't mention it was using ORM. In fact I said exactly the opposite.