# htmlspecialchars to escape SQL string for Cake PHP 2

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm performing an SQL query in my Cake PHP 2.10 application and need to insert a value that's retrieved from another query. I've been reading the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) for Cake 2 and came across this note:

> If you use this method, be sure to properly escape all parameters using the value() method on the database driver. Failing to escape parameters will create SQL injection vulnerabilities.

I can't seem to find the `value()` method, so have opted to use the `htmlspecialchars` function provided by PHP.

Given that my value is taken from another query, the risk of a malformed value or tampered value is quite low, so is this fine?

How else can I escape my string to ensure it doesn't mess up the query?

My query in my function looks like:

```php
$redirection_key = $this->request->query['r'];
$redirect = $this->Redirect->findByRedirectionKey($redirection_key);

$appID = htmlspecialchars($redirect['Redirect']['application_id']);
$applicationPayday = $this->Application->query("SELECT * FROM tlp_applications WHERE id = $appID");
```

Is `$appID` okay in this instance?

Comment: No, that's _never_ fine, _never ever_, `htmlspecialchars()` is not suitable for escaping query values! That being said, no matter where the data stems from, if you pass something to a query, the only sensible thing is to assume that that the data could be dangerous! Please see **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647877/how-to-prevent-sql-injections-in-manually-created-queries/41650249#41650249**

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking, how would I change my above to put `$appID` into my query?

Comment: How is it _not_ what you were asking for? It shows how to escape data using arguments for prepared statements, and it also shows how to do it manually via the datasource's `value()` method.